# Use r.js to package a library written using RequireJS for reuse in other RequireJS applications

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

So lets say I have some small bit of library code that I develop and test in isolation.  I use RequireJS during development and have a root level file that depends on 1 other file. So it's `define` looks something like...

```
// lib/main.js
define(['lib/dep1'] function(dep1) {
  ...
})
```

I run r.js on the code which results in `dist/myLibrary.js`, which looks something like this:

```
define('lib/dep1',[], function(){...})
define('lib/main',["lib/dep1"], function(dep1){...})
```

If I pull `myLibrary.js` straight into another project it won't work.  Nothing is defining itself as the module for that file.  But if I append an actual module definition, it works.

```
define('lib/dep1',[], function(){...})
define('lib/main',["lib/dep1"], function(dep1){...})
define(['lib/main'], function(lib) {
  return lib;
})
```

And the `['lib/main']` seems to be scoped to the module, because if I have an actual `lib/main` in my app, it doesn't get used.

Questions:

1. Regarding the scoping, is that the normal behavior? The fact that `lib/main` is recognized as a module id from the same file rather than going to look for it someplace else.  If I import 10 such libraries that all have a `lib/main`, they won't collide?
2. Is there a better way? I am at least initially unconcerned about supporting the non-AMD use case as this is all internal lib development and we all use RequireJS.  So within a fully AMDed environment, is there another, better way to do this?  Assuming there's no pitfall to this approach, it seems fairly simple and boilerplate to support.